# Migrate to docker desktop 2.2 generate acl errors

Tags: php, docker, symfony4, docker-desktop

## Description:

One of my team member has migrate docker desktop to version 2.2.
Since, the php service won't start due to setfacl command from an entrypoint.sh.

## Context:

We are working on a api-platform project in version 2.4.7.

#### Php Dockerfile:

```
# the different stages of this Dockerfile are meant to be built into separate images
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#target


# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.3
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.15
ARG VARNISH_VERSION=6.0


# "php" stage
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS api_platform_php

RUN  apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS icu-dev openldap-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install ldap  && \
    docker-php-ext-enable ldap && \
    apk del .build-deps


# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        file \
        gettext \
        git \
    ;

ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.17
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip \
    ; \
    pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    ; \
    pecl clear-cache; \
    docker-php-ext-enable \
        apcu \
        opcache \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .api-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN ln -s $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/php/conf.d/api-platform.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/api-platform.ini

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
# install Symfony Flex globally to speed up download of Composer packages (parallelized prefetching)
RUN set -eux; \
    composer global require "symfony/flex" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative; \
    composer clear-cache
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/api

# build for production
ARG APP_ENV=prod
ARG TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost
ARG SENTRY_DSN=<SENTRY_DSN>
ARG BLACKFIRE_PROFILE_ON=false

# prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every changes in the source code
COPY composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock ./
# do not use .env files in production
RUN echo '<?php return [];' > .env.local.php
RUN set -eux; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest; \
    composer clear-cache

# copy only specifically what we need
COPY bin bin/
COPY config config/
COPY public public/
COPY src src/

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync
VOLUME /srv/api/var

COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

# Blackfire php probe
RUN version=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") \
    && curl -A "Docker" -o /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -D - -L -s https://blackfire.io/api/v1/releases/probe/php/alpine/amd64/$version \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/blackfire \
    && tar zxpf /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -C /tmp/blackfire \
    && mv /tmp/blackfire/blackfire-*.so $(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")/blackfire.so \
    && printf "extension=blackfire.so\nblackfire.agent_socket=tcp://blackfire:8707\n" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/blackfire.ini

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]


# "nginx" stage
# depends on the "php" stage above
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_nginx

COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /srv/api

COPY --from=api_platform_php /srv/api/public public/


# "varnish" stage
# does not depend on any of the above stages, but placed here to keep everything in one Dockerfile
FROM cooptilleuls/varnish:${VARNISH_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_varnish

COPY docker/varnish/conf/default.vcl /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

#### docker-entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php-fpm "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'php-fpm' ] || [ "$1" = 'php' ] || [ "$1" = 'bin/console' ]; then
    PHP_INI_RECOMMENDED="$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production"
    if [ "$APP_ENV" != 'prod' ]; then
        PHP_INI_RECOMMENDED="$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development"
    fi
    ln -sf "$PHP_INI_RECOMMENDED" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

    mkdir -p var/cache var/log
    setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX var
    setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX var

    if [ "$APP_ENV" != 'prod' ]; then
        composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction
    fi

    echo "Waiting for db to be ready..."
    until bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; do
        sleep 1
    done

#   if [ "$APP_ENV" != 'prod' ]; then
#       bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --no-interaction
#   fi
fi

crond -L /srv/api/logs/crond.log -b

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

## Commands in cause (in docker-entrypoint.sh):

`mkdir -p var/cache var/log
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX var
setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX var`

## Errors (durring php service up):

`setfacl: var/log: Not supported`
`setfacl: var/log/dev.log: Not supported`

## Search line:

A new feature of docker-desktop is "***New file sharing implementation***" that replace (a kind of file sharing system) Samba by FUSE. It's made  for developpers like us  to improve performances when running symfony or react app through docker.

- docker-desktop 2.2 release note [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/)
- a docker blog post about FUSE [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/new-filesharing-implementation-in-docker-desktop-windows/)

Do anyone has a same probleme and maybe a solution ?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you doing to build your php machine? etc etc. This question does not contain enough data.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] before asking here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: At a guess, `mkdir -p var/cache var/log` is trying to create folders at the top of the container's filing system. Try `mkdir -p /var/cache /var/log` instead.

Comment: It's seems to have many similar issues with this 2.2 release [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues). We probably wait a bit for answers from the docker team. Ps i'm still working by my side on this projet so i could'nt update my docker-desktop for testing this.

Comment: Did you solved the issue? I have the same problem after having commented `# VOLUME /srv/app/var/` in `Dockerfile`, at the start of the build of the dev image of PHP.